# In a hosted website ,embed web pages from other local web server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I host a website, in that i called few web pages from other server (locally hosted on other server). I embed those pages in Iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://192.168.1.11  /DSS/DashboardEngine.aspx?DashboardID=Muda\PSI\OverviewWL" scrolling="auto" runat="server" width="99.8%" height="475px"></iframe>
```

When i access website in its local network that time embedded  pages are showing perfectly

[image]

If i access website from outside then those embeded pages are giving local url access issues.

[image]

How can we call those local web pages from other local server efficeintly on hosted website.Plese help..

Comment: Ican't reach your iframe URL : http://192.168.1.11/DSS/DashboardEngine.aspx?DashboardID=Muda\PSI\OverviewWL. You are miss something?

Comment: @OlegYudovich iframe url is "http://192.168.1.11/DSS/DashboardEngine.aspx?DashboardID=Muda\PSI\OverviewWL"

Comment: This is exactly URL i was posted. I get server error 404: http://screencast.com/t/K1gKktsT5

Comment: its like http://192.168.1.11/dss/dashiboard

Comment: @OlegYudovich that is local network ip.you cannt reach there.I am embedding local pages in main website

Comment: local pages from other web server i need to embed with hosted server.from outside it cannt access that local host page.so giving error

Comment: So if it local network, you can't call it from another local machine. You need to upload this project to sever...

Comment: but if i open website in same network then it is opening those pages.but from outside it is not opening because in my iframe i call pages with local ip.and it is calling from client side script.can we call these pages server side and display it in main page?

Comment: @OlegYudovich if website hosted on a server and then if we are in same network then we can access that website.

Answer (score 1):

Iframe's content is requested by the user's browser. If user's browser cannot access that IP address it will not be able to get to the content. You are using a local IP address 192.168.1.1 which you can ping from within network but when outside of the network it will not be reachable.

It is just like you say to the browser to read a website like any other but then to display it within the iframe borders.

http://192.168.1.11  /DSS/DashboardEngine.aspx

needs to be something like

http://yourdomain.com/DSS/DashboardEngine.aspx

Other option for you is to access that content on the server side and include it in your response.

Comment: that solution i am looking now.how can i access those local web pages on the server side.and thanks atleast you understand my problem

Comment: If it is a static content you can use Response.Write but looking at your example looks like it is some interactive map plug in.

Comment: i have to show that page in a section of hosted website.any server side solution?

Comment: yeah one interactive map page is there.can we embed these pages on server side?